# Closed set of $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to find a subset $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, given the product topology, such that $W$ is closed and $p_{1}(W)$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, where $p_{1}:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the projection map.

For a subset to be closed in $ \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ surely it must be the product of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$ so how can that project onto a not closed set in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Products of closed sets are always rectangles. Can you think of a closed set in the plane that is not a rectangle?

Comment: A closed disc is a subset of the plane, but how can this be projected onto R?

Comment: @user520830 You should look at the definition of the [Projection (set theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(set_theory)).

Comment: A couple useful facts to keep in mind.  Heine-Borel says that compact is equivalent to closed and bounded for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Projection maps are continuous and the continuous image of a compact set is compact, in particular it's closed.  So any set that satisfies your conclusion must be unbounded in $\mathbb{R^2}$: if it were bounded, it would be compact, so it's image would be compact, and therefore closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your sentence *For a subset to be closed in $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ surely it must be the product of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$* is wrong. A circle is closed in $\mathbb  R^2$ but is not a product of closed subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Now regarding your initial question, $A= \{(x,1/x) \mid x>0\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$. However $p_1(A) = (0,\infty)$ is not closed.